# How to hide url in angular?

Tags: url, angularjs, view, routes

Is it possible to not using angualar routes, because if I defined an routes like:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/home')
})
```

my url will look like www.app.com/#home,

I dont want to change url, just www.app.com nice and clean, in this case how to defined template for defferent controller and how to load the template in ng-view, and how to pass url parameter?

any idea?

Comment: Maybe the way in this post is a good solution [https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do that with the built-in routing mechanism because `path` is required for every route. However, you can use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) library in order to create URL-less states and navigate to them using [either code or directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state).

I created this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7os1bZ55izeC6KVBTa0D?p=preview) to demonstrate how to use `ui-router` to navigate among states without modifying URL.

Comment: nice it works, one thing to notic that how to define root state like .otherwise()

Comment: You meant to prevent users from entering incorrect URL or developers from typing the wrong state name? What is the use case you're looking for?

Comment: ui-router dose hide the url but when refresh the page the state is reseted, I strill need url to locate the current page

Comment: Because there's no URL, it will always default to the designated root page, i.e. the one with `url: ''`. If you want to "remember" location, you have to code it yourself. An idea is listen to state change event, then store the current state name in cookie or localStorage. Then later in app startup, go to that state programmatically.