# How to navigate through views without changing the url?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

Using angular 1.5, I'm developing some features and views, where I pretend to perform some navigation, keeping the url untouchable

example:

1) Access to url myapp.com, shows login form 
2) login success (do stuff, doesnt matter now) 
3) view changes with other content but url stays the same

Few examples i've seen by far, each view has diferent urls to perform the navigation

example:

login: url: myapp.com/login

Comment: It seems that this is what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435967/how-to-hide-url-in-angular

Answer (score 1):

You should use the states for this, having a 'home' state with a url, then other states but not declare urls:

```
.state('home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: "foobar.html",
  controller: function($scope) { 
    // Check your login here;
  }
})
.state('home.page-two', {
  url: "",
  templateUrl: "foobar-two.html",
  controller: function($scope) { }
})
.state('home.page-three', {
  url: "",
  templateUrl: "foobar-three.html",
  controller: function($scope) { }
})
```

Then to move between the states, use the $state.go() to load your particular state once you've made sure the login has been processed to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

you will not be able to use the angular "views" for this, because those are bound to different urls.
what you can do is implement your own "view-system" using ng-show, ng-if and ng-include.

Comment: And what about _mask_ the url, to keep the idea that it stays the same ?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that. can the url in the top bar of the browser change when you are changing views or not?

Comment: I'ts seems it can't be done, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435967/how-to-hide-url-in-angular